# URL for laravel app on MAMP

Tags: apache, laravel, mamp

I am a total noob at this. Got MAMP, Laravel. My webroot is /Applications/MAMP/htdocs. Normally to hit my laravel application I have to go to:

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/public/index.php
```

What files do I have to configure to be able to access it like this:

```
http://myapp.com/index.php
```

I've read docs about adding an entry into my hosts file but when I tried adding the following entry `127.0.0.1  myapp.com` I still have to do `http://myapp.com/myapp/public/index.php`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit your .htdocs file to forward myapp.com to 127.0.0.1 and then set up a DocumentRoot in your httpd.conf file. You can set up multiple redirects if you do it properly.

Comment: Do you mean forward myapp.com to 127.0.0.1 in my hosts file? Also I have no idea what to write to my httpd.conf file